# ngIf other html element exists?

Tags: html, angular

I have a website that each component displays a table with some information that is gathered through a service talking to a backend. It can sometimes take a couple seconds for that data to be returned, and the table to be displayed. The website also has a footer which is the same for every component. This is what the main page looks like, with each individual component being within the `router-outlet` element:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Ulti-Reference</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li><a style="color: white;padding: 10px;" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'USA']">USA</a></li>
        <li><a style="color: white;padding: 10px;" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'World']">World</a></li>
        <li><a style="color: white;padding: 10px;" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'Africa']">Africa</a></li>
        <li><a style="color: white;padding: 10px;" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'Asia_Oceanic']">Asia Oceanic</a></li>
        <li><a style="color: white;padding: 10px;" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'Europe']">Europe</a></li>
        <li><a style="color: white;padding: 10px;" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'Pan_American']">Pan American</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<footer style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" >
  Brought to you by:
  <a style="color: #003162" href="https://twitter.com/pittultimate"><img src="assets/logo_pitt.jpg" height="80"></a>
  <a style="color: #003162" href="https://www.pittultimate.org/"><img src="assets/logo_sabah.png" height="55"></a> |
  <a style="color: #003162" href="https://usaultimate.org/">USA Ultimate</a> |
  <!-- <img src="assets/logo_usaultimate.svg" height="45"> -->
  <a style="color: #003162" href="">Matthew Bourland</a> |
  <a style="color: #003162" href="http://ultimatehistorybook.com">Joe Seidler<img src="assets/logo_seidler.jpg" height="70"></a>
</footer>
```

Right now, any time a page loads, if the component inside the `router-outlet` element takes a few seconds to load, the `footer` loads at the top of the page, before moving down whenever the table element is generated. Ideally, I'd like the footer to not display *until* that inner table is generated. Is there a way to do this? I'm imagining wrapping the footer in some sort of `*ngIf`, but I'm not entirely sure what  I should be checking for.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in another project and this is what I did:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="!dataRetrieved" [ngIfElse]="content">
  <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #content>
 //your tables code + your footer
</ng-template>
```

Basically what it does is that it checks for tables contents and if they're not ready yet, it just shows a loading spinner and when the data is finally retrieved, it loads all of the page (the table and the footer) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `RouterOutlet` provides a `activate` event when a new component is instantiated (see [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description)). You could listen to that to show your footer.

Alternatively, you might consider simply aligning your footer to the bottom of the page, no matter if the router outlet actually contains a component, that way you don't need to hide it at all. (Actually that behaviour is what I'd personally expect of a footer.)